# Convex subsets and Linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $E$ be a convex subset of a normed space $X$ and $x\in E$.

Then $x\in \overline{E}$ if and only if $\Re f(x)\geq 1$ for every $f\in X'$ such that $\Re f\geq 1$ on $E$ and $\Re f(x)\leq 1$ for every $f\in X'$ such that $\Re f\leq 1$ on $E$..

I have no idea how to start at the least..

There is another exercise that is given just before this and i think this would be useful...

> Let $E$ be a closed convex subset of $X$. Then $E$ is intersection of all the real half spaces containing it. Real half space is 
>      $\{x\in X : t\leq Re f(x)\}$..

As $\overline{E}$ is convex, closed, we see that
$\overline{E}=\bigcap \{a\in X : t\leq \Re f(a)\}$

I have no idea how to proceed.. Please suggest something.

Comment: Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: @jochen... Ictried using that as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one side, let $x \in \bar E$, choose a sequence $(x_n) \in E^{\mathbf N}$ such that $x_n \to x$. If now $x' \in X'$ is given such that $\Re x'|_E \ge 1$. Then, as $\Re x'$ is continuous, we have 
$$ 1 \le \Re x'(x_n) \to \Re x'(x) $$
That is $\Re x'(x) \ge 1$. Along the same line we see that $\Re x'|_E \le 1$ implies $\Re x'(x) \le 1$.

For the other direction, let $x \in X \setminus \bar E$, then, by Hahn Banach, there is $x' \in X'$, such that 
$$ \sup_{e \in \bar E} \Re x'(e) < \Re x'(x) $$
Choose $\alpha \in \mathbf R\setminus\{0\}$ such that 
$$ \sup_{e \in \bar E} \Re x'(e) < \alpha < \Re x'(x) \tag +$$
Dividing $(+)$ by $\alpha$, we get if $\alpha > 0$: 
$$ \sup_{e \in \bar E} \Re \alpha^{-1}x'(e) < 1 < \Re \alpha^{-1} x'(x) $$
and are done, if $\alpha < 0$, we get
$$ \inf_{e\in \bar E} \Re \alpha^{-1}x'(e) > 1 > \Re \alpha^{-1}x'(x). $$

Comment: Thanks... Now i see how simple this...